# Build a voltage-controlled voltage source out of discrete components

Tags: mosfet, bjt, prototyping, voltage-source

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I need to build a voltage-controlled voltage source, but I don't have any opamps (or time to order them). I have been working for several hours trying to simulate a circuit in LTSpice that will do the job, with no luck. (BJTs were never intuitive to me, and it's been a while since my circuits class!)

I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me out, and hopefully the next poor schmuck who comes across this type of problem will too.

I need to turn a 0-5V DC signal into a 0-15V (not-necessarily-high-current) source.  Here's what I have to play with:

- all the 1/4 watt resistors one could want
- a bag of 2N4401 NPN BJTs
- a bag of 2N4403 PNP BJTs
- several nameless 60V 30A n-channel MOSFETs
- various capacitors
- 24V, 15V, and 5V power rails (avoiding the 15V would be nice, but not nessecary)

Comment: voltage-controlled voltage sources don't exist in reality.

Comment: @Andyaka what's a noninverting opamp circuit to you?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a noninverting opamp circuit and not a VCVS and 22/7 isn't pi (99.96% accurate)

Comment: well it supplies a voltage proportional to the voltage at another point?

Comment: And has limited current capabilities and falls over at high frequencies and has offset errors and noise.

Comment: sure, like any other circuit symbol you could think of, the actual implementation is non-ideal.

Comment: Try Googling on "discrete operational amplifier".

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSaBwqmnoKEUXhSx-coc8Qn4PaxaMooloDBNCd05Jwm8pb2iBRamg

Comment: And now to be sensible: What accuracy? What frequency response? What output impedance? What load characteristics? What efficiency? What noise limits? What temperature range? How big/small?

Comment: There are many methods. How PRECISE must zero in produce zero out? How PRECISE must +5in product +15 out?

Comment: You're sure you don't have time to order op amps? It'd probably take more time to work out an op-amp-less method than for the op amps to ship. And if you really need them now, you can pay extra for expedited shipping. I'd recommend buying some general purpose op amps anyway, to avoid situations like this in the future.

Comment: @Reid Rankin: do input and output side share a common GND? If yes, then please don't call it a VCVS. Requiring that input and output side may not share common GND makes it **much** more difficult to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Vopq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are THREE inverting stages in the feedback loop. A huge Cmiller across Q6 is what I suggest (I've no simulator right now). The emitter cap is to boost HF gain so the Cmiller takes effect.

Comment: Note that testing and optimizing this design will probably take longer than ordering and waiting for opamps, though :)

Comment: And this discrete circuit has weak drive to ground.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf This is perfect. Thank you for helping me in my hour of need, and more importantly, providing me something I can study and compare to my (15-20) failed designs to figure out where the heck I'm going wrong.

Comment: @ Reid Glad you can study this. Note the Darlington inputs with separate collector output (4 collectors) allow Vin to reach down to GND.

Answer (score 1):

A voltage-controlled voltage source *is* an amplifier (ok, a voltage-source amplifier with high input impedance, idealized), so your best bet when trying to build such a thing yourself out of discretes is probably getting one of the many old-school BJT audio amplifier circuits – or HF amplifier circuits (both possibly reprinted hundreds of times in amateur radio magazines, until everyone lost the original design motivations), depending on the frequencies you need to amplify.

Comment: The frequencies I need are between 0 and 10 hertz. (As in, it's all DC.) I tried a couple precooked BJT amp circuits, but I got a significant DC offset, and I can't use that.

Comment: well, imperfections like DC offset can basically only be met (to some, very limited, degree) with hand-tuning using resistive dividers and/or finely tuned semiconductors. I'm afraid if you need a precision thing, you can't use "run off the mill 2N44xx" transistors without much ado.

Comment: What is also very important to know is whether input and output side of VCVS share a common GND. In general this is not the case for a VCVS; it is, however, normally the case for an amplifier.

Comment: @Curd They do share a common ground.

Comment: @ReidRankin I kind of was assuming that, but yeah, that's a very ... restrictive understanding of an VCVS. A VCVS would be able to generate a controlled voltage regardless of potential, and that would be a whole lot harder to build!

Comment: @Reid Rankin: then please don't ask for a VCVS. That's like asking for an off-road vehicle when all you need is a simple car.